# How To Insert Value From Textarea To Database With "|" Characters?

Tags: php, insert, textarea

My Table **tapphim** have **tap** column, **link** column and **player** column
I want insert data before "|" and after "|" on different columns, example i'm input this value to textarea :

```
1|fuuka-vietsub|https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tDKPbZ_gaNZrcYHt-tQtcF-TH0hMzGFi/view?usp=sharing
```

Will insert **1** to column **tap**,**fuuka-vietsub** to column **link** and **https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tDKPbZ_gaNZrcYHt-tQtcF-TH0hMzGFi/view?usp=sharing** to column **player**

I Have this code from index.php :

```
<form action="api.php" method="post">
<textarea name="themphim" id="themphim"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save"></input>
</form>
```

File api.php :

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
// Please give for me code
... 
//
}
?>
```

Thanks everybody !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` to break using a separator |

```
$string = '1|fuuka-vietsub|https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tDKPbZ_gaNZrcYHt-tQtcF-TH0hMzGFi/view?usp=sharing';
$strToArray = explode('|',$string);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($strToArray);
```

Output

```
Array
(
 [0] => 1
 [1] => fuuka-vietsub
 [2] => https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tDKPbZ_gaNZrcYHt-tQtcF-TH0hMzGFi/view?usp=sharing
)
```

Now you can use array key `0 -> tap`, `1 -> link`, `2 -> player`